# Traits and implementations in Rust

Tags: traits, rust

I have the following types:

```
trait Monster {
    fn attack(&self);
    fn new(int) -> Self;
}

struct CookiesMonster {
    cookies: int,
    hungry_level: int,
}

impl Monster for CookiesMonster {
    fn new(i: int) -> CookiesMonster {
        CookiesMonster { cookies: i, hungry_level: i + 1 }
    }

    fn attack(&self) {
        println!("I have {:d} cookies!!", self.cookies)
    }
}

struct Dummy {
    count: int
}

impl Dummy {
    fn new(i: int) -> Dummy {
        Dummy { count: i }
    }
}
```

Now, this works:

```
let monster: CookiesMonster = Monster::new(10);
let dummy = Dummy::new(10);
```

But this doesn't:

```
let monster = CookiesMonster::new(10);
```

Why can't I call the new method directly on the CookiesMonster type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that calling the methods on the trait instead of on the type implementing the trait allows cases like this to be unambiguous: Consider if you added the following code to your example:

```
trait Newable {
    fn new(int) -> Self;
}

impl Newable for CookiesMonster {
    fn new(i: int) -> CookiesMonster {
        CookiesMonster { cookies: i, hungry_level: 0 }
    }
}
```

In this context, `Monster::new` still works, but `CookiesMonster::new` would be ambiguous.

(In this example, it figures how *which* implementation of the trait to use based on type inference.  A generalized syntax such as `Trait::<for Type>::static_method` has been discussed as a way to explicitly write down one's intentions, but I am not sure how far along that is.)

Update circa 15 July 2014: the "Unified Function Call Syntax" proposal tracks the work alluded to in the previous paragraph.  See [Rust RFC PR 132](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/132/files?short_path=a469353#diff-a469353da9b0f7d92f0e04b6815f2c52).  My understanding is that UFCS as described in that RFC would actually allow for you to write `CookiesMonster::new` when `Monster` is the only trait in scope that both (1.) provides the `new` method and (2.) is unambiguously implemented for `CookiesMonster`.

Comment: I considered mentioning this in my answer, but this "feature" disappears once you start considering methods on `self`. If I have two (in-scope) traits that both define `frob(&self)` then `obj.frob()` is ambiguous even though they came from separate traits. So I'm not convinced that this really matters very much.

Comment: I don't understand why would CookiesMonster::new be ambiguous. It seems pretty clear to me what it would do. EDIT: Got it, makes more sense now.

Comment: @KevinBallard actually, in that case, the compiler says "error: multiple applicable methods in scope". Here is an example https://gist.github.com/nata79/8372600

Comment: @AndréBarbosa: Yes, "multiple applicable methods in scope" means it's ambiguous.

Answer (score 12):

Because that's how traits work at the moment. Static methods in traits must be called on the trait, and not on the implementor of the trait.